# Authentication as a Sails hook

Tags: sails.js

As the [doc](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/Hooks) says, `hooks allow Sails code to be shared between apps and developers without having to modify the framework`. There are some public boilerplates on GitHub for social or local authentication but I think the hook system is much more interesting for doing this than cloning a special project each time.

1. Is that the way Sails hooks should be used?
2. Should we create one hook for each type of authentication system (like passport strategies) or have a global auth hook?

Thanks by advance!

Comment: Hook can be use to do this for sure ! I plan to make a hook like this with passport strategies. My idea is to create one hook that can handle all strategies (with config file to enable/disable them). But if you want you can make one hook for one strategy.

Answer (score 3):

I just start to implement a hook with passport embedded here :
https://github.com/jaumard/sails-hook-passport

Try it and let me know if you have some problems.

Comment: Pretty good news, I'm definitely going to try it out this week end